# C++ Searching for occupied fields in 2d map

Tags: c++, search, dictionary

I have a 2d map in my rts. On the map there are some units. I want to check if there is any unit in range of another. The units range is given in fields. See the image:

[image: Ranges]

On the pic none of units (red, blue, green) can attack each other. I want to, for example check, for example if there is any units in range of blue. The answer is no. I know the blue's range and position, I also know positions of the rest. I also know if the map xy is occupied. How can I check this?

Comment: if those ranges are only 1 to 4 in size, i would create a bitmap for them, and then check if a point lays on that bitmap or not. simple and allows you to create any shaped moves easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to iterate over all points `(x + i, y + j)` around your unit at `(x, y)` such that

```
|i| + |j| <= R ,
```

where `R` is the range of attack. (This is a disk in the *L*<sup>1</sup>-metric.) So, like this:

```
for (i = -R; i <= +R;  ++i)
{
    jRange = R - abs(i);
    for (j = -jRange; j <= +jRange; ++j)
    {
        // access (x + i, y + j)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can halve the outer loop by unrolling:

```
for (i = 0; i <= R; ++i)
{
    jRange = R - i;
    for (j = -jRange; i <= +jRange; ++j)
    {
        // access (x - i, y + j)
        // if (i > 0) access (x + i, y + j)
    }
}
```

As @Alink says, you'll have to handle the map boundary in some way or another.

Comment: The unrolling counts twice the column x. Also, depending how you handle out-of-map access, it might be worth it to use min(0, -R) and max(map.width, R) for loop's boundary.

Answer (score 2):

### On other answers (too long as comment):

Pathfinding is really wrong here. First of all, we have a grid with no restrictions and equal costs. Using any kind of pathfinding is neither necessary nor makes sense at all. I get that you are thinking ahead in a way that this exact property might change / usually is different for RTS games, but I really think we should stick to the exact problem if the author carried it out precisely and quite well.

Especially, A* is a terrible, terrible choice:
Dijkstra calculates shortest paths to all destinations from a given source node. A* uses the fact that you often have one distinct destination and a heuristic can be used to "guide" Dijkstra in the right direction. It makes you reach the interesting destination earlier and therefore you pay a small overhead. If you want to check areas "around" some source node (the unit here), this just counter-productive.

Bitmaps will have the problem of aligning them with the grid. Either way there surely are ways to optimize and check more they once field at once, but those are just optimizations, imho.

### On the problem itself:

I have no experience with games at all, so this is w.r.t of the abstract problem you outline above. I have added some speculations on your RTS application but take them with a grain of salt.

Simply checking all fields around a unit, as suggested by Kerrek SB is pretty good. No unnecessary field is checked and all fields are accessed directly. I think I'd propose the same thing.

If the number of the checks from the question greatly dominates the number of unit movements (I doubt it, because of the "real-time" thing), it might be possible to precompute this problem for every unit and update it whenever a unit moves. I'll propose something that is more hungry for memory and most probably inferior to the straightfoward approach Kerrik SB proposed:

If a unit U moves to field F, it will:

- notify all Unitis registered at F that they now can attack something
- register itself at all the fields around F that it can now reach and
- at the same time check if one of this fields is already occupied so that it could attack right away
- remember all those fields to "unregister" once U moves away in the future

Consequently, each unit will know if it has something in range and does not have to recalculate that. Moving a unit will trigger recalculation only for that given unit and fields will simply notify only relevant other units.

However, there is memory overhead. And "real-time" and plenty of units moving all the time will largely decrease benefits. So I have a strong feeling this isn't the best way to go, either. However, depending on your requirements it might also work very well.

Answer (score 1):

Create a bitmap for the ranges of each unit, this will allow you to shape them in any shape you want.

Simplified example:

```
char range1[] = 
"010"
"111"
"010";

char range2[] = 
"00100"
"01110"
"11111"
"01110"
"00100";
```

And so on...

then just check if the point lays on the bitmap (you have to figure that out yourself).

Comment: Well, You mean me doing it up to 100? ;D

Comment: @kittyPL, this is why you should read the comments of your question and answer to them.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a pathfinding algorithm, especially since map squares can be occupied, you'll need a pathfinding algorithm sooner or later. A* would probably be the easiest one to implement for you and perform well enough for your given scenario. It is very well described on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star), and googling it should return a lot of results for you as well as sample code.

You would basically calculate a path between each entity and another. If that path exceeds the given range for the unit, it is out of range. This could of course be optimized so that you will not continue checking once all the range is exhausted.

Comment: I implemented A*, and BFS, but i think it has nothing to do with this :D (maybe im wrong)

Comment: Depends, if you want to know if the units actually can move to one another, you will need it. If they are going to simply shoot at eachother and can shoot through terrain, then you can go with a simple distance check. But since you are showing actual moves and saying that the squares can be occupied on the map then you are not going to get away with just checking if bitmaps overlap. You will need to actually do the pathfinding to see if the units can reach eachother

Comment: They can shoot through map ;D so just simple range check

Comment: Then why not simply use a vector going from one unit to the other, and take the length of it? There is no need to iterate or do anything fancy if you simply want to know how far apart they are?

Comment: Doing that you won't get exactly the same shape that you are showing now, but it will be a whole lot faster and the guns will behave more naturally, since the distance will be in "real" units instead of grid bound unit movements.

Comment: It would be faster? It gives O(n^2) complaxity and Kerrek's answer is O(n) complex... So how can it be faster?

Comment: No, a range check would be faster. A pathfinding check is slower.

Comment: Depending on the number of units checking ranges between ALL of them, is much more effort than checking only the fields around a given unit.

Comment: There is (R+1)*R*2+1 cells at range R, so if you are using big range and don't have many units, then better iterate through N units while calculating Manhattan distance. Also, if you have a list of *enemy* units you can half this.